# Unemployment benefits for EU blue card holders in Germany

Tags: germany, eu, blue-card, non-citizens, unemployment-benefits

I started my Blue Card job in Berlin a year ago. Now, I am changing my job. I applied for an appointment at the immigration office on 8th June. I was supposed to start my new job on 15 August 2022. However, I have still not received an appointment.

Hence, my new company has sent me a new contract. They are saying that since I have not received an appointment yet, I should postpone my starting date to 15 September. This means that I will be jobless for around a month. I cannot stay at my current job after 14 August 2022.

In this case, can I apply for some sort of unemployment benefits? Considering that I will be jobless because of the state's slow processing times and not because of my own fault. I am a non-EU citizen.

I emailed a job center to ask this. However, I don't fully understand their answer.

> You can apply for benefits according to SGB II, but then your requirements for the Blue Card are no longer met.
>
> The Foreigners' Registration Office makes all decisions in this regard.
>
> You must contact the Foreigners' Registration Office in order to find a solution for the period in which you are not working.
>
> With an application for benefits in the jobcenter, the prerequisite for the blue card is clarified.
>
> We must inform the Foreigners' Registration Office of this
>
> Benefits from the jobcentre can only be granted with a Blue Card if the need is not covered by the income from work.

Does this mean I am not eligible because I earn enough to have a Blue Card? Or because I am not an EU-Citizen?

Comment: Until July 2022, I have 12 months since I started the job last August @MarkJohnson

Answer (score 1):

> Please add the **exact** amount of calender months where contributions have been paid (check your pay slips).
> **Note**: a partial calender month counts as a full month: 2021-08-15 to 2021-08-31 and 2022-08-01 to 2022-08-14 counts as **2 months**. *SGB II* would only apply if you have **less** than 12 months of contributions in the last 30 months.  [Arbeitslosengeld: Anspruch, Höhe, Dauer - Bundesagentur für Arbeit](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/finanzielle-hilfen/arbeitslosengeld-anspruch-hoehe-dauer)

> Until July 2022, I have 12 months since I started the job last August

In otherwords, including August 2022, 13 months.

You are therefore eligible for **normal** unemployment benefits (*SGB II* does **not** apply).

Apply **now**, starting on the 15th of August.

Bring the payslips and the resignation letter of the old job (to 2022-08-14), the new contract starting on 2022-08-15 **plus** appointment attempts and the new letter from the new employer.

This will prove that the **only reason** for the unemployment is the lack of an appointment to get the approval.

This should be approved **and** possibly speed up the approval of the new job to avoid (if still possible) the unemployment all together.

---

> Does this mean I am not eligible because I earn enough to have a Blue Card?

**Assumption**: The Jobcenter was unaware, at the time they wrote the letter, that you are already eligible for unemployment benefits.

For *SGB II* (also called *ALG II* or *Hartz IV*) financial support would only paid out if you have no other means to support yourself. ([ALG 2: Voraussetzungen, Einkommen, Vermögen - Bundesagentur für Arbeit](https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/arbeitslosengeld-2/voraussetzungen-einkommen-vermoegen))

In this case, you would have an income for August (working until the 14th of August), so any support for August is unlikely.

For September you would have to reveal the amount of your savings before they would determine if any payment for September would be made.

> Or because I am not an EU-Citizen?

Citizenship has nothing to do with eligiblity for unemployment benefits or other financial support.

Comment: If I get my appointment in the beginning of September, that would mean that I can start the job by 15th September. Hence, I might have some income for the second half of September too. Would that mean that I automatically won't be considered for any benefits for September either? Note that I live with my husband.

Comment: @x89 Since you are eligible for **normal** unemployment benefits, you will get unemployment benefits from the 15th of August until you start working. **You should apply now** (suppling the documents stated in the first part of my answer). They **might** speed up the job approval, so that you could start on the 15th of August **if you do it now** (in July).

Comment: I started the process. Now, I need to get this filled from my employer: https://www.arbeitsagentur.de/datei/arbeitsbescheinigung_ba013140.pdf. My HR said that they'll look into it but they think I am not entitled to receive Arbeitslosengeld since I have resigned myself and not vice versa. Also, she said usually there is a lock of 3 months before you get money from the state. Lastly, she said that she's not sure if she can issue the form before I actually leave the company. Any ideas about this?